# Laravel - select temporary column where temporary column

Tags: laravel, eloquent, where-clause

```
$search_str = "full name search";

$user = App\User::selectRaw("CONCAT(`f_name`, `l_name`) AS `fullname`")
        ->where('fullname', 'LIKE', '%$search_str%')
        ->get();
```

Based on the code above, the column `fullname` actually does not exist in DB Table. `fullname` column is just a temporary column.

But when I use it on `where` clause, Laravel return an error:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'fullname' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `CONCAT` function in your where filter.

```
$search_str = "full name search";

$user = App\User::selectRaw("CONCAT(`f_name`, `l_name`) AS `fullname`")
    ->whereRaw("CONCAT(`f_name`, `l_name`) LIKE '%?%'", [$search_str])
    ->get();
```

Comment: It would be nice to not to repeat the same `CONCAT()` function. But anyhow, I think this is the only way. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use Having for aliases. See below reference link.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset